# How to read 100GB of Nested json in pyspark on Databricks

Tags: json, pyspark, databricks

There is a nested json with very deep structure. File is of the format json.gz size 3.5GB. Once this file is uncompressed it is of size 100GB.

This json file is of the format, where Multiline = True (if this condition is used to read the file via spark.read_json then only we get to see the proper json schema).

Also, this file has a single record, in which it has two columns of Struct type array, with multilevel nesting.

How should I read this file and extract information. What kind of cluster / technique to use to extract relevant data from this file.

Structure of the JSON (multiline)

This is a single record. and the entire data is present in 2 columns - in_netxxxx and provider_xxxxx
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmFkP.png)

Comment: provide the data example so that can get more idea about the issue .

try to read the json file without zipped .

Comment: sample data is a single line with multiple structure (array & maps)

Comment: if you share the data and how you want to get the out put  then it will help alot

Comment: the size of the json is 80GB, I am looking for ways to read the contents of the file in chunks

Answer (score -1):

I was able to achieve this in a bit different way.

1. Use the utility - Big Text File Splitter -
   BigTextFileSplitter - Withdata Softwarehttps://www.withdata.com › big-text-file-splitter ( as the file was huge and multiple level nested) the split record size I kept was 500. This generated around 24 split files of around 3gb each. Entire process took 30 -40 mins.
2. Processed the _corrupt_record seperately - and populated the required information.
3. Read the each split file in a using - this option removes the _corrupt_record and also removes the null rows.
   spark.read.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").json(file_path)
4. Once the information is fetched form each file, we can merge all the files into a single file, as per standard process.